# How to list text file extensions

Tags: c#, file-type

I found this code for the image extensions:

```
var imageExtensions = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    .SelectMany(codec => codec.FilenameExtension.ToLowerInvariant().Split(';'));
```

now, I want to list text files extensions; like `.rtf` or `.txt`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define an array yourself with the supported file formats yourself.

The reason for this is that, in contrast to the images encoders, there is not a well defined list in the framework available.

Ofcourse you could go for the [Mime types](https://ok.commercetools.com/magento-migration?utm_campaign=WhitePaper&utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=paidsocial&utm_term=Benelux&utm_content=WP_Magento_Migration_Benelux&hsa_acc=507427343&hsa_cam=604690466&hsa_grp=144706646&hsa_ad=76291676&hsa_net=linkedin&hsa_ver=3) but even that list is not complete. (scroll to the text section)

Do understand that there are tins of text formatted extensions around, and since the interpertation of most of them is trival, you don't need decoders to read (some of) them.

I'll name a few;

- txt
- rtf
- doc
- docx
- xml
- xsd
- ini
- config
- log
- err
- json
- yml
- yaml

and many more.

Also, there are a lot of applications arround defining their own format, and providing their own functionality like images, tables and such. So in contrast to an image file, a `text` file isn't really well defined in such a matter.

Comment: see the update with the link: it might help you to get a better list :)